# Use a single content database on two web applications

Tags: 2007, content-database

Can we use a single content database on two web applications in SharePoint 2007?

I created a new application and a site collection. I want to use my old (existing) content database on the new web application and site collection.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Two web applications cannot share a content database as per design.
I am not sure what you want to achieve with this but if you want to expose the same web application with two url say one for internet and one for intranet you can extend the web application to two different zones.This will create more web sites in IIS

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

The problem is : i have a web application with 4 site collection on production with single app pool, now i crated a back file of existing particular site collection let say "Mysite(site collection)" and restored successfully on new web application site collection let say "MyNewSite(site collection)" all the content with files successfully restored .........

Comment: .......but the problem is my new one is created separate database and and i don't want to leave both database because there is only one will be in use which is new one, and i can't delete old database because old one having single database for my all rest of site collection, that's why i want to use same database and want's to delete new database................Or

Please suggest me the best solution.
Thanks.

Comment: I still can't get you...one way you are saying you want to use new one then saying wants to delete new database...let both web app use their respective database whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use one content database for two Web applications. One content database attached to single web application in a given time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. The problem is : i have a web application with 4 site collection on production with single app pool, now i crated a back file of existing particular site collection let say "Mysite(site collection)" and restored successfully on new web application site collection let say "MyNewSite(site collection)" all the content with files successfully restored .........

Comment: .......but the problem is my new one is created separate database and and i don't want to leave both database because there is only one will be in use which is new one, and i can't delete old database because old one having single database for my all rest of site collection, that's why i want to use same database and want's to delete new database................Or Please suggest me the best solution. Thanks

Comment: You have to have two Content Databases, one for web App1 and 1 for Web App2. Their is no alternate of this...why you want to move 1 site collection to new web app? can you move all site collection to new web app and delete the old one?

Comment: Because user experiencing out of memory error, that's why we are planing to separate at least two site collection with individual Application with own app pool. We can create new app pool for each site collection but we want to separate with new web application.

Comment: if user experience out of memory error than your situation will worse with another app pool. App Pool put extra burden on server and grab the memory. I think your best bet either increase the memory or optimize your farm.

Comment: Thank you very much Waqas sarwar. I am trying to optimize the farm.

Comment: Could you please suggest me which types of farm optimization need to reduce the memory issue? I am new in sharepoint.

Comment: its depend what is your farm arch?

Comment: Hi, Waqas  You are right i created separate app pool but still getting issues, how can optimize the firm could you help me to optimize the firm??